# Multi-paragraph attribute in AsciiDoc

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I have a two-paragraph text that gets repeated fairly often. How could I avoid the repetition?

For now I have:

```
:something-1: Blah blah blah +
blah blah blah +
blah blah blah

:something-2: Blah blah blah +
blah blah blah +
blah blah blah
```

And then:

```
--
{something-1}

{something-2}
--
```

Is there a way I could put both paragraphs into one attribute? It would be even better if I could put the block into the attribute too.

This doesn't work:

```
:something: Blah blah blah +
blah blah blah +
blah blah blah +
+
Blah blah blah +
blah blah blah +
blah blah blah
```

The plus on the empty line and the second paragraph are not parsed as part of the attribute definition.

Another option is putting the two paragraphs in a separate file and using the `include:` macro. But creating a separate file every time I face this problem would create some clutter. It also makes it harder than necessary to go from 1-paragraph definitions to 2-paragraph definitions. I'd rather have a single "glossary" section (or document) which contains all these repeated term definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if multi-paragraph attributes are possible, but [selective imports](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#by-tagged-regions) definitely are! I now have a `glossary.asciidoc` file:

```
tag::something[]
--
Blah blah blah

Blah blah blah
--
end::something[]
```

And I can import this section by saying:

```
include::glossary.asciidoc[tag=something]
```

A major advantage of this approach is that text formatting inside the snippet works.

Comment: I'd say this is probably the best way of doing this unless you want to create an extension which will generate content.